# My div box isn't showing up, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext

Okay, so Codecademy gave me this code to create what looks like box using div and background-colors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css...

```
div {
     background-color: #cc0000;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
}
```

It worked fine. I got a red box. Afterwards I tried to do it on my own but its not working. My code's pretty much exactly the same but don't know what's going on. Here's mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href"boxes.css"/>
        <title> Boxes </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>


</html>
```

the css...

```
div {
    background-color: #2D1132;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

If someone could explain how I can make this work that would be great!

Comment: Try adding an equals sign after the HREF in your second example

Comment: `href"boxes.css"` is wrong.

Comment: "Sublimetext tag" is invalid for question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not referenced the stylesheet correctly.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href"boxes.css"/>
```

Should be:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="boxes.css"/>
```

Comment: Hahaha, wow I went over it so many times and never caught that. Thanks